# how to create new instance of viewModel in koin every time

Tags: android, mvvm, viewmodel, koin

Am Using **Koin** as **Dependency injection pattern** in my project, I need to create new instances whenever i load fragment/activity, now am using the following pattern,  Any solution for that it might save lots of time.

```
private val homeViewModel: HomeViewModel by viewModel()
```

Comment: you can do it in BaseActivity or BaseFragment if you have this class

Comment: i have both,  how can i dot it from there?

Comment: Thanks for `by viewModel()`! Instead we used self-written method to create Shared ViewModel, that's why `init` block was called only once for several fragments.

Answer (score 1):

The question is why you want new instances everytime? The whole concept of `ViewModel` is to retain the same instance and data. `viewModel {}` creates new instance everytime you inject it unless it is not shared.

Don't know why it is not working for you, but I think you can use `factory{}`  instead of `viewModel{}`.

```
factory{
    // this is because you need new instance everytime.
    HomeViewModel()
}
```

Comment: there is no api in Koin for: private val homeViewModel: HomeViewModel by factory { HomeViewModel() }

Someone would want new instances to clear live data cache.

Answer (score 0):

> Define ViewModel as an abstract in BaseFragment class and set value when you extend your BaseFragment.

```
abstract class BaseFragment<Binding : ViewDataBinding, ViewModel : BaseViewModel> : Fragment(){
            protected var bindingObject: Binding? = null
            protected abstract val mViewModel: ViewModel

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
            bindingObject = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, getLayoutResId(), container, false)
            return bindingObject?.root
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        performDataBinding()
    }

    @LayoutRes
    abstract fun getLayoutResId(): Int

    private fun performDataBinding() {
        bindingObject?.setLifecycleOwner(this)
        bindingObject?.setVariable(BR.viewModel, mViewModel)
        bindingObject?.executePendingBindings()
    }

}
```

> And in your fragment

```
    class FragmentNew : BaseFragment<FragmentNewBinding, FragmentNewVM>() {
       // Here is the your viewmodel imlementation. Thus when you create fragment it's by default override method
       override val mViewModel: FragmentNewVM by viewModel() 

       override fun getLayoutResId(): Int = [fragment layout id like "R.layout.fragment_new"]
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are going to want to forego using `by viewmodel` and instantiate the class directly. You can get global (scoped) variables through `getKoin().get()`.

```
private val viewModel = HomeViewModel(getKoin().get())
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you create an instance of the ViewModel via `by viewModel()`. In my case I used another way and created one Shared ViewModel for several fragments. `init` block was called once.